# How to inject a Maps Android v2 API Key into an application?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

It seems that is not possible to set an API v2 key programatically, so is there any other method to set this value after build.

Comment: I doubt it. Using the new Gradle-based build system, you will have better flexibility in the value you compile into the app, but I think it has to be in the `<meta-data>` in the manifest one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

i think **its not possible** because, During the build process, your Android projects are compiled and packaged into an .apk file, so you can't change it after build !

official documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html